# Default shell program in emacs

Tags: shell, emacs

How can I determine the default shell program in Emacs?
On an Ubuntu machine when I go to term mod (M-x term) or Emerge, it tries to run /bin/bash

On anther machine, Emacs tries to run /bin/false and I want to fix this problem.
Could you please help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Looks like it uses the environment variable $SHELL.

Comment: Try `SHELL=/bin/bash emacs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Steve Howard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/446649/steve-howard), The problem can be solved by changing SHELL to /bin/bash

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a user configuration issue - Emacs is most likely using the default shell and it's a common way to prevent users from getting shell access by setting the shell to /bin/false or /bin/nologin (or variations thereof).

The remedy is to get the sysadmin to give you shell access as in a proper shell configured for your user account instead of /bin/false.